# Make sure google sheets script button run only once at a time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a button on a sheets similar to the one described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).

The problem is I want to avoid users clicking it multiple times at once (because the script sends messages).

I noticed that the drawing button don't pass an event to the function. Is there a way to accomplish this? I've been searching but didn't found an answer, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/) for this?

Comment: Thanks, this seems the appropriate service! The others answers will do the trick 90% of time

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, it is possible with [Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service.html)

E.g. you set-up a script property within the first call of the script. Within the following calls the script checks if the property already exists, and if it does - it does not run the rest of the code.

Sample:

```
function onlyOnce(){
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var myProperty = scriptProperties.getProperty('already_called');
  if (!myProperty){
    showMessageBox();
    scriptProperties.setProperty('already_called', 'YES');
  }
}
function showMessageBox() {
  Browser.msgBox('You clicked it!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**A Short Time Debouncer**

I think I'd try it this way so that it automatically resets itself after a short time.

```
function onlyOnceInAShortTime() {
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  var cached = cache.get("already_called");
  if(cached=="YES") {
    Browswer.msgBox('You click it');
    return;
  }
  cache.put('already_called', 'YES' , 20);//remains for twenty seconds
}
```

[Class Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache.html)