# Copy values to next column(if blank) in the same row. If not blank, copy to the second column(if blank) in same row. Repeat

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, share

Disclaimer: Im very new to google scripts. I jumbled together this code with mixed success.

When I run the script, it works fine with the first two attempts. Then it doesnt work after that because column Q now has values in other cells within the column and the script is technically correct but not running at intended. I need to ignore column Q cells that are not blank and still run the script to copy P values to the other cells in column Q.

Also, when column Q with in the same row is not blank, I need to copy the value from column P to column R (if blank). Rinse and Repeat script...

```
  function copyVals () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!P2:P");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange('Q2:Q')
  var destRange2 = destSheet.getRange('R2:R')
    if (destRange.isBlank()) {
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear ();
  } 
    if (destRange2.isBlank()) {   
   source.copyTo (destRange2, {contentsOnly: true});
   source.clear ();
  }
}
```

Comment: Mind to share how your sheet table look like with image? Because if different row many have random empty value in different column, then you will need `for loop` to solve it. Unless only entire col value are empty, then it will be easier to address the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to do the blank check for each cell separately

However, if you do it wiht the Apps Script method `isBlank()` - this will make your code a bit slow.

I suggest you to

- retreive the existing values both in the source and destination ranges with [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- check for each of the destinations values either those are empty and replace the empty values through source values
- assign the modified values back to the sheet with [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Sample code:

```js
function copyVals () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var source = sheet.getRange ("P2:P" + lastRow)
  var destSheet = sheet
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange('Q2:Q' + lastRow)
  var destRange2 = destSheet.getRange('R2:R' + lastRow)
  var sourceValues = source.getValues().flat()
  var destValues = destRange.getValues()
  var dest2Values = destRange2.getValues()
  sourceValues.forEach(function(value, i){
  console.log("i" + i)
    if (destValues[i][0] == "") {
      destValues[i][0] = value
    } 
    if (dest2Values[i][0] == "") {
      dest2Values[i][0] = value
    } 
  })
  destRange.setValues(destValues)
  destRange2.setValues(dest2Values)
  source.clear ();
}
```

UPDATE

If you want to copy to column Q and R alternately, you can use [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to save the  run count of the script and execute different code blocks for odd and even number.

Sample:

```js
function copyVals () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var source = sheet.getRange ("P2:P" + lastRow)
  var destSheet = sheet
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange('Q2:Q' + lastRow)
  var destRange2 = destSheet.getRange('R2:R' + lastRow)
  var sourceValues = source.getValues().flat()
  var destValues = destRange.getValues()
  var dest2Values = destRange2.getValues()
  
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
  var myProperty = scriptProperties.getProperty('timesCalled')
  if (!myProperty){
    myProperty = "1"
    }

    myProperty = JSON.parse(myProperty)
    var isOdd =  myProperty % 2
    if(isOdd){
    sourceValues.forEach(function(value, i){
      console.log("i" + i)
      if (destValues[i][0] == "") {
        destValues[i][0] = value
      }  
    })
    destRange.setValues(destValues)
    
  } else{
    sourceValues.forEach(function(value, i){
      if (dest2Values[i][0] == "") {
        dest2Values[i][0] = value
      } 
    })
    destRange2.setValues(dest2Values)
  }
  source.clear ()
  myProperty++
  scriptProperties.setProperty('timesCalled', JSON.stringify(myProperty))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This sample code is almost correct. Just need to not copy to both columns first. Example: copy P value to empty Q column in same row, leaving blank R column blank until the next entry from P. Then copy to that entry to R.   Like this:  P-->blank Q, then P-->blank R

Comment: So how is the script meant to know when to copy to Q and when to R? Maybe it would be better to make to separate functions and to call one when you want to copy to Q and the other when you want to copy to R?

Comment: A trigger will let be set for the script to copy to blank Q, then to blank R, same row. Q and R will mainly have two separate values. Two separate functions may work but the R column function needs to check the Q column value before adding the text to it.

Comment: Please confirm if I understood it correctly and clarify: If a certain row in Q is empty - copy Q to R for this row. If the row is not empty in Q but is empty in R  - copy to R instead. If both Q and R are not empty  - do not do anything for this row. And if both Q and R are empty?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. It should go as follows:  P column gets an entry, the entry is copied to column empty Q. When P gets another entry, it will copy that to empty R column. All in same row. If both are empty, copy to Q first

Comment: Any ideas on the last comment?

Comment: So you want to run the script only two times and the script should know either it is the first or the second time? Or will there also be a 3rd time, 4rth time etc?

Comment: Yes, That is correct. Actually, I would like to add more if possible.

Comment: I can think of an approach using [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) which would allow you the number of times the script has already run and then implement the flow accordingly (if script runs the 1st time - do a, if it's the second time do b etc.). But I still do not understand what you want to happen e.g. during the 3. or 4th script run. So maybe you can give it a try yourself and then come back with specific problems you encounter.

Comment: Can I add those script properties to the existing script?

Comment: Yes! See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60060592/11599789).

Comment: Thanks for your direction. My skillset is not there yet to combine these properties. But much appreciated!!

Comment: Should I use a "break" statement to stop and separate the two functions? I need Q to be the first cell populated then R.....Also I really just need 2 option for now Q & R. If I add more they will be S and T and they will follow the same sequence P-->Q, P-->R, P-->S, P-->T.

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample of how you can use script properties to determine either the script run number is even or odd  - and copy to the respective column. Please adapt this sample to your case if needed and should you encounter issues - feel free to create a new post for a specific question / issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I can add 3, 4...to this with every trigger also?  P-->Q, P-->R, P-->S, P-->T...